# Making a Discord Bot in Python - AttributeError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've recently tried to create a simple bot in discord with Python Code.
I'm testing just the first features to DM a user when he joins the server

Here is my code:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  #load .env files

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')  
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')  

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name=GUILD)  

    print(
        f'{client.user} has connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )                                                            #debug
    
    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])  

    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')  #debug

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.creat_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord Server!'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andre/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andre/repos/github/discord_project/bot.py", line 30, in on_member_join
    await member.creat_dm()
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'creat_dm'
```

Can anyone help me with this annoying bug?
I've seen articles that show `member.create_dm()` being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there is a member.create_dm() https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_dm#discord.Member.create_dm
But you spelled it wrong "member.creat**e**_dm()"

You may try to store the DM channel into a variable, so you can call it later.
(Just my opinion on making the code better)

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    dmChannel = await member.create_dm()
    await dmChannel.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord Server!)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer posted is correct but you should not call [`create_dm()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.create_dm)frequently, [`member.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.send) works the most time.

Docs: [`create_dm()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.create_dm)

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord Server!)
```